# The dimension of the annihilator space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and   $X^{*}$ its dual (topology). For $M$   a given subspace of $X$, we denote by  $M^{\perp}$  the annihilator  of $M$ defined by:
$$M^{\perp}:=\{f \in X^{*} \text{ such that } f(x)=0 \text{ for all } x \in M\}.$$
Suppose that $M$ is closed  then the quotient space $(X/_M)^{*}$ isomorphe to $M^{\perp}$ and so  $\mbox{dim}(M^{\perp})=\mbox{dim}(X/_M)^{*}.$ I have found in many books that   $\mbox{dim}(M^{\perp})=\mbox{dim}(X/_M).$ But it is well known that in general we don't have the equality   $\mbox{dim}(X/_M)= \mbox{dim}(X/_M)^{*}.$  Can you explain to me why ?

Comment: Isn't $dim V=dim V^*$?

Comment: In the case of $\mbox{dim}V<\infty$  we have $\mbox{dim}(V)=\mbox{dim}V^{*}.$ But in general we have $\mbox{dim}(V)\leq \mbox{dim}V^{*}.$

Answer (score 0):

Take any $f\in M^{\perp}$ then if we take $$h([x]_M )=f(x) $$ then $$|h([x]_M )|=|f(x)| =|f(x+y)|\leq C||x+y||$$ for any $y\in M,$ so it defines a continous linear functional on the quotient space $X/_M .$ Thus $M^{\perp } \xrightarrow{\sim}\left(X/_M\right)^* .$

On the other hand if $h \left(X/_M\right)^*$ then the equation $$f(x) =h([x]_M ) $$ defines a continous linear functional on $X$ such that $f(x) =0$ for $x\in M.$ Thus $\left(X/_M\right)^* \xrightarrow{\sim} M^{\perp } .$
So we obtain that $\left(X/_M\right)^* \cong M^{\perp } .$

Comment: Thank you, but you don't understand my question,  i know that $(X/_ M)^{*}\sim M^{\perp},$ but this does not imply that $\mbox{dim}(X/_ M)= \mbox{dim}M^{\perp},$ because in general we have $\mbox{dim}(X/_M)\leq \mbox{dim}(X/_M)^{*}.$

Comment: In many cases it is true, If for example $X$ is separable Banach space  then $\mbox{dim} V =\mbox{dim }V^*$ this is because $\mbox{dim}V^{*}\leq \mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} =\mathfrak{c} $ and $\mbox{dim} V\geq \mathfrak{c} .$

Comment: Yes. But in general it is not true.